# Stratus 2 Beta hacks or customization

Tags: soundcloud-stratus

I'm currently using Stratus 2 Beta to stream music from soundcloud to my website. At the bottom of the player there are various links to different pages. One is a link to stratus's website. Is there anyway to hide those buttons to make a cleaner player?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case anyone stumbles upon it…

Two ways: 
1) Edit the CSS to hide what you want and pass it as a theme (one of the options) to the player.
2) Grab the code from http://stratus.sc/stratus.js edit it and use it on your own server.

One point though: SoundCloud ToS requires a link to their site; as stratus is an official player it counts as the link, so you probably shouldn’t remove that one (unless you’re putting the link somewhere else).